# Partial playback using playbackDuration/startTime in Google Cast Chrome API (v3)

Tags: google-cast

I am trying to cast just a snippet of a file (say, only from 00:00:30 to 00:00:40) from a Chrome sender to the default receiver.  Reading the [API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/) documentation for `LoadRequest`, `MediaInfo`, and `QueueItem`, it seemed like I should be able to do this with some combination of these.  In particular, the first queued item (loaded with `CastSession#loadMedia`) would need `LoadRequest#currentTime` set to the offset (30 seconds in my example above) and `MediaInfo#duration` set to the duration (10 seconds in my example), while subsequently queued items would set `QueueItem#startTime` and `QueueItem#playbackDuration` to the offset and duration (respectively).

However, this isn't happening in practice.  I can confirm that the queue on the receiver has these fields set, but the no matter how I go about this, I can't get the right snippet to play.  When I add the first media item as described above, the receiver just plays the track from beginning to end, neither respecting the offset nor the duration.  Since the combination of `LoadRequest#currentTime` and `MediaInfo#duration` is a bit odd, I tried using only the `QueueItem` method (add the first media item with `autoplay = false`, add another queue item, remove the first, and then start playing the queue).  In this case, the offset was still not respected, and the duration ended up being (*very* strangely) the **sum** of `startTime` and `playbackDuration` (in addition, any subsequently queued items would load, and then "finish" playing without starting, which I also can't figure out).

Does anyone else have experience with this part of the API?  Am I reading the documentation incorrectly and what I'm doing just isn't supported, or am I just piecing things together incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand why you are attempting to use a queue with multiple items. First, the duration field is not what you think it is; it is not the duration of play back that you want, it is the total duration of the media that is being loaded, regardless of where you start or stop the playback. In fact, in most cases, you don't even need to set that; the receiver gets the total duration of the media when it loads he item, at least in the majority of the cases. The currentTime should work (if it is not, please file a bug on our [SDK issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list)) and alternatively, you can load a media (with autoplay off) and "seek" to the time you want and then play. To stop at a certain point, you need to monitor the the playback location and when it reaches that point, pause the playback.